# "StackExchange" is created with sharepoint?

Tags: discussion, tags

I like "Ask Question" and "Tags" features in StackExchange, who can tell me that if "StackExchange" is created with sharepoint?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network - not SharePoint

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow are not created with SharePoint. They use a custom ASP.NET solution.

For more details of the technology stack see  [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network).